# How to use array concate or combine methods in java loop

Tags: java, arrays, string, concatenation

**BEFORE ANSWERING KINDLY READ THIS BRACKETED PARAGRAPH CAREFULLY**
(The following code is just a **mini model of my large code in practice**. Actual code contains **thousands** of

words and  their arrays further processed for many required things. For example 'i am a lazy boy' will be

converted into ' [i1] [a2,m2] [a1] [l4,a4,z4,y4] [b3,o3,y3]', and after concatenating them[i1, a2, m2, a1, l4, a4, z4,

y4, b3, o3,y3]).

Here is the full mini model code:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

public class WordSplit {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str= "i am a lazy boy";
        String[] word = str.split("\\s");
        //String[] chars = word.split("(?!^)");


        for(int i=0; i<word.length; i++){



          String [] such= word[i].split("(?!^)"); 


           /*upto here five such arrays has been creataed as:
            such : [i]
            such : [a, m]
            such : [a]
            such : [l, a, z, y]
            such : [b, o, y]
            */

      /* HOW TO USE HERE  ObjectArrays.concat()OR ArrayUtils.addAll( );
      SOME ITS EQUIVALENT TO GET THIS OUTPUT:

            [i,a,m,a,l,a,z,y,b,o,y]

      */


       }

    }}
```

The code creates five arrays:

```
such : [i]
such : [a, m]
such : [a]
such : [l, a, z, y]
such : [b, o, y]
```

But I am expecting that by some method they are to be concated as in the steps of the loop as

```
such: [i]
such: [i, a, m]
such: [i, a, m, a]
such: [i, a, m, a, l, a, z, y]
such: [i, a, m, a, l, a, z, y, b, o, y]
```

I need help to get the above output.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Just write it manually, there is no need for a library function, it should not me more than 5 lines of code...

Comment: You have mentioned ArrayUtils.addAll(). Whats stopping you from using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use ArrayUtils, you could do it as follows.

Initialise such outside your loop to be empty:

```
String[] such = new String[0];
```

Then inside your loop replace your current String [] such= line with:

```
such = ArrayUtils.addAll(such, word[i].split("(?!^)"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
"i am a lazy boy".replaceAll(" ", "").toCharArray();
```

The type here is `char[]`, but it is actually better than your original `String[]`

Comment: I understand that, but he splits his original string, create an array for each and then merge all the arrays while he can have the answer directly.